# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec - no such file or directory

Tags: java, runtime, exec

Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdAry );` same with one string as array.

```
Exeption Cannot run program "libreoffice": error=2, No such file or directory
```

if I enter the exact command string into a terminal it works.

here is command string:

```
libreoffice --impress --show /home/xxx/ImpressTests/ShowTestOne.odp
```

Linux Mint 19.3
Same java program works fine on Windows 10.

on Linux terminal shows this after program works successfully. Resaving file does not fix this.

```
xxx@LM19RyzenVM:~/CodeJava$ libreoffice --impress --show /home/xxx/ImpressTests/ShowTestOne.odp
func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26
xxx@LM19RyzenVM:~/CodeJava$
```

Is this libreoffice error causing the failure? This worked before. How do I find out more about error? This is running in VirtualBox VM. Can that possibly be a difference? I'll go test on real machine now.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that it worked in the VirtualBox VM before? I assume VirtualBox also had libreoffice. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. It worked in VBox before with Linux Mint 19.3 guest, and it worked on real LM machine. I just confirmed that I broke it for both VM and HW, so it's not a VM issue.

Comment: Here's a jar that worked, not perfectly, but worked. https://sourceforge.net/projects/impressshowrunner/files/ Here is code https://github.com/windyweather/WBTutorial No spaces in pathnames. That's what I'm trying to fix. Again, works on Win 10 just fine.

Comment: Woops. Version 09 on sourceforge is broken too for LM. It says "file does not exit" Hummm

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118373

It's a known bug. For some reason, Windows doesn't care. But on Linux launched from Java, Java trashes the child process if it writes to SYSERR.
So maybe I can wrap it in a script on Linux to cover the bug until the fix arrives.